Categorisation of alerts in Prometheus and grafana
I want to do categorisation of alerts in Prometheus and grafana if cpu usage is between 70 and 75 then medium , if cpu usage is between 75 and 80 medium and usage is greater than 80 then critical please help me how can I achieve this
I already have a condition for to calculate in percentage however when I do and between query it fails
Please guide how to proceed this

If what you are talking about is Prometheus alerts (configured in alerts.yml of Prometheus), you'd need to create three different alerts. Not 100% sure, but I think same is true for Grafana.

First step is to define alert rules into prometheus.yml.
Add this alert.rules to main config prometheus :
rule_files:
 - 'alert.rules' 

Then fill the alert.rules with this content :
sudo nano /etc/prometheus/alert.rules
groups:
- name: NodeExporter
  rules:
  - alert: VMOutOfMemory
    expr: node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes / node_memory_MemTotal_bytes * 100 < 10
    for: 2m
    labels:
      severity: warning
    annotations:
      summary: VM out of memory (instance {{ $labels.instance }})
      description: "Node memory is filling up (< 10% left)\n  VALUE = {{ $value }}\n  LABELS = {{ $labels }}"

  - alert: CPUMediumUsage70to75
    expr: (100 - avg by (instance) (rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle"}[5m])) * 100) > 70 and (100 - avg by (instance) (rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle"}[5m])) * 100) <= 75
    for: 2m
    labels:
      severity: medium
    annotations:
      summary: CPU usage between 70% and 75% (instance {{ $labels.instance }})
      description: "CPU usage is between 70% and 75%\n  VALUE = {{ $value }}\n  LABELS = {{ $labels }}"

  - alert: CPUMediumUsage75to80
    expr: (100 - avg by (instance) (rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle"}[5m])) * 100) > 75 and (100 - avg by (instance) (rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle"}[5m])) * 100) <= 80
    for: 2m
    labels:
      severity: medium
    annotations:
      summary: CPU usage between 75% and 80% (instance {{ $labels.instance }})
      description: "CPU usage is between 75% and 80%\n  VALUE = {{ $value }}\n  LABELS = {{ $labels }}"

  - alert: CPUCriticalUsage
    expr: (100 - avg by (instance) (rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle"}[5m])) * 100) > 80
    for: 2m
    labels:
      severity: critical
    annotations:
      summary: CPU usage above 80% (instance {{ $labels.instance }})
      description: "CPU usage is above 80%\n  VALUE = {{ $value }}\n  LABELS = {{ $labels }}"

Now restart prometheus service :
sudo systemctl restart prometheus
You can check alerts in { http or https }://{ prometheus-url }:9090/alerts
